# Which truthy values have no property?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, optional-chaining

I am trying to write the shortest readable code to access the property of a variable that I have no information about, but I want this property access to be safe:

```js
const x = getXSomehow();

const y = x.z; // 1
const y = x?.z; // 2
const y = x != null && x.z; // 3
const y = x && x.z; // 4
```

1. Might throw if `x` is `null` or `undefined`
2. Would be perfect, but I can't use optional chaining (for some reason out of the scope of this question)
3. Works & is used by other libraries like lodash and coffeescript to access props in a null safe way, but reads ugly
4. I wanna use this, but this would fail if there exist something truthy in JS that doesn't let you access its properties - can this even happen? All I can think of is `null` and `undefined`, but perhaps there exist an exotic JS value that is both truthy and throws on property access

Comment: I'd take a closer look at 2. If browser compatibility is the issue, could you integrate Babel into your build process (it should already be present anyway, in a reasonably professional project IMO), and then use optional chaining, and have it transpiled down to ES5/ES2015 for production? (if not, OK, but that's what I'd do)

Comment: Nope, that's an issue with babel + jest + istanbul that doesn't handles optional chaining, I mean it could theoretically, but our team collectively decided that this work would be too costly! But yes I would agree if it wasn't for that detail

Answer (score 1):

> this would fail if there exist something truthy in JS that doesn't let you access its properties - can this even happen?

It could, but it'd be pretty strange - like a getter that may throw:

```js
const obj = {
  get prop() {
    throw new Error();
  }
};

console.log(obj.prop);
```

Or a Proxy with the same sort of thing.

But this same method would result in each method throwing - all of 1, 2, 3, and 4; it's too strange to be worth worrying about in normal code, I think.

If it were me, I'd re-examine (2) to see whether it'd be at all possible to change your build process to integrate optional chaining. Otherwise, you'll have to choose between (3) and (4).